# How to use Push Notification using asp.net(SOAP web service) in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am new in iOS and facing problem regarding to using push notification in objective c. I found very tutorial for push notification but none for asp.net web service. I am using SOAP web service and don't understanding where to call it so that I can receive push notification form web service.In which method of AppDelegate.m I need to call web service so that I can receive notification.

My web service is some thing like this.

```
POST /webservice.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: URL
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/Method"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Method xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <UserId>string</UserId>
    </Method>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why somebody devote question I don't understand how to use this web service and where?

Comment: I already answered your question, try my code ,if you have some other question, pl let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *soapStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\
                      <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"\
                      xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\
                      <soap:Header>\
                      </soap:Header>\
                      <soap:Body>\
                      <login xmlns=\"targetNameSpace address/\">\
                      <param1>test</param1>\
                      <param2>test</param2>\
                      </login>\
                      </soap:Body>\
                      </soap:Envelope>"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"The endpoint address of your wsdl document"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
// GET/POST
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%zd", soapStr.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request addValue:@"nameSpace/methodName" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
// body information
[request setHTTPBody:[soapStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
// here is the task of the POST request to your soap web service
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
// when run at this location, the request is successed,you can get the result in the response.
     NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"success Session-----result：%@----url address：%@", result, response.URL);
    if (error) {
// when code run at here , the request is failure ,you can get the error message.
        NSLog(@"Session----failure----%@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];

// here is call the task to request in fact.
[task resume];
```

this is my code about how to request soap web service. you can try this.

Comment: In which method I need to call web service method so that I can receive push notification

Comment: don't forget to change the `soapStr` `url` `SOAPAction` with your soap web service information.

Comment: sorry, i have some mistake about understand what effort you want...
when your app custom click some thing or some button ,send the userid to web service ,then web service push a notification to your app. is this what effort you want?

Comment: I need to know In which method of AppDegedate I need to call this webservice.

Comment: if you want the notifacation show when user open your app immediately, call the request method in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`.But, you must make sure you register the nofitication before call the request method.

Comment: then method will get call every time?

Comment: you don't understand the push notification how it works in iOS,if you want realize when your web service push a notification , your app receive it , you need register the push notification and overwrite some method about push notification in the `appdelegate.m`,also you need realize different method for receive notification because the system version of iOS is not same.suggest you to read some iOS API document about the push notification at this url `https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications`

Comment: if i want to subscribe notification do i need to subscribe everytime? I use .net api c#, i can subscribe it once but how do i implement it so that if i want to edit it or remove subscription or check that i have subscription